# Task Cancellation Exception after 3rd call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new here and I hope you can help me with a problem I've got.
I'm trying to call some API's from Unity UWP, but every time on the third call I've got an Task Cancellation Exception, no matter what the order is of calling the api's.

Here is my piece of code:

```
public class DashboardManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text Status;

    async Task Awake()
    {
        await GetPerformanceInfo().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await GetProductionInfo().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await GetChecklistInfo().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


    private async Task GetChecklistInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient((HttpMessageHandler)ApiHelpers.HttpClientHandler);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiHelpers.PlantApiBaseAddress.CheckBaseUrl(true));

            var plantApiClient = new PlantApiClient(httpClient, default); // await ProgramManager.ServiceProvider.GetService<PlantApiClient>()
            var checklists = await plantApiClient.GetChecklistWidgetInfo(UserSettings.Location);

            //Status.text = "Checklist OK";
        }
        catch (LogoutException ex)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginScene");
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Status.text = "Checklist: " + ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status.text = "Checklist: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public void OnClickButton(string guid)
    {
        GlobalManager.CurrentChecklistID = guid;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("ChecklistsScene");
    }

    private async Task GetPerformanceInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient((HttpMessageHandler)ApiHelpers.HttpClientHandler);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiHelpers.PlantApiBaseAddress.CheckBaseUrl(true));

            var plantApiClient = new PlantApiClient(httpClient, default); // await ProgramManager.ServiceProvider.GetService<PlantApiClient>()
            var perfInfo = await plantApiClient.GetPerformanceWidgetInfo(UserSettings.Location);

            //Status.text = "Performance OK";
        }
        catch (LogoutException ex)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginScene");
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Status.text = "Performance: " + ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status.text = "Performance: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private async Task GetProductionInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient((HttpMessageHandler)ApiHelpers.HttpClientHandler);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiHelpers.PlantApiBaseAddress.CheckBaseUrl(true));

            var plantApiClient = new PlantApiClient(httpClient, default); // await ProgramManager.ServiceProvider.GetService<PlantApiClient>()
            var prodInfo = await plantApiClient.GetProductionWidgetInfo(UserSettings.Location);

            //Status.text = "Production OK";
        }
        catch (LogoutException ex)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginScene");
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Status.text = "Production: " + ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status.text = "Production: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Awake Task, the 3rd call always fails with an TaskCancellation Exception.
If I change the order, it always fails on the third call.
There is nothing wrong with the api calls, because they are working as expected.  If I just call one or two, everything works fine, but when I call a 3rd one, it fails.

What's happening here, I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What is the stack-trace of the exception? Is it a `TaskCanceledException` or an `OperationCanceledException`? Have you run your debugger with the "Break on all first-chance exceptions" option enabled? (Debug > Windows > Exceptions > Check the top-level "Common language exceptions" checkbox)

Comment: You should **not** be using `await xxxx..ConfigureAwait(false);` as an attempt to perform the continuation on a thread pool thread.  `MonoBehaviour` methods such as `Start()`, `Update` and `Awake` are executed on the Main Thread.  Your call to say `GetChecklistInfo` may be on a worker thread where `SceneManager.LoadScene` will most likely fail.  Unity requires that most of the API be called from the main thread.   Unity being a CLR host may choose to ignore `ConfigureAwait()` so that the continuation is on the main thread anyway. You should get into the practice of not using it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
@MickyD I don't agree you should call the api's from the main thread, but you probably right that LoadScene would fail, but I wasn't there yet.  I tried to figure out what was going on and now I know it was a bug in a previous version of unity.  Now my code is working fine.

Comment: @AlainCuypers _"I don't agree you should call the api's from the main thread,"_ - it's completely fine to make `async` I/O (inc HTTP) calls whether or not they are in a worker thread because the `await` on the I/O object (in this case `plantApiClient`) will make use of IOCP.  What I am saying is that calls to the majority of **Unity's API** (graphics, scenes, GPU) [must be called on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69938628/585968).  So if you intend to act on the result of said `async` operation, say update a texture, you will need to thread marshall it back to the main thread.

Comment: By the way, I just replicated your `async Task Awake()` and whilst I began on thread `#1` **Main Thread** (good), by the time `GetChecklistInfo` had completed the `Awake` method was now on thread `#44` (worker)!  So whilst great for calling slow HTTP servers, `ConfigureAwait(false)` would be troublesome if say you wanted to update a texture.   Now you could place all the `awakes ...ConfigureAwait(false)` into another async method and simply have `async Task Awake() { await DoMyAsyncStuffAsync();  UpdateTexture() }` and all would be fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity SceneManager.LoadScene() does not work when being called from external event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935829/unity-scenemanager-loadscene-does-not-work-when-being-called-from-external-eve)

Answer (score 1):

Damn, this took me 2 wasted days, just to figure out this was a bug in Unity 2020.3.11f1.
I installed version 2021.2.8f1 and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Bug? What bug? Citation?  You sure it wasn't just because you commented out `Status.text = ...` in your worker thread?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry Guys, I was away for a while.  What I meant was that I now target my project to unity version 2021.2.8f1 and used the same code and now everything is working correctly.
When I target the project with version 2020.3.11f1 it isn't working, so I assume it's a bug in that version of Unity.